# How to define compile time ternary literal in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, user-defined-literals

In **Chapter 19** of the **4th** edition of the [C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321958322) book, there is an example of defining a ternary number literal using a template technique, but the example does not compile. I tried to fix it in the way it looks right to me, but it still does not compile.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr uint64_t ipow(uint64_t x, uint64_t n)
{
  return n > 0 ? x * ipow(x, n - 1) : 1;
}

template <char c>
constexpr uint64_t base3()
{
  static_assert(c >= '0' && c <= '2', "Not a ternary digit.");
  return c - '0';
}

template <char c, char... tail>
constexpr uint64_t base3()
{
  static_assert(c >= '0' && c <= '2', "Not a ternary digit.");
  return ipow(3, sizeof...(tail)) * (c - '0') + base3<tail...>();
}

template <char... chars>
constexpr uint64_t operator""_b3()
{
  return base3<chars...>();
}

int main()
{
  cout << 1000_b3 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Clang** gives the following error:

```
error: call to 'base3' is ambiguous
  return ipow(3, sizeof...(tail)) * (c - '0') + base3<tail...>();
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:49: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'base3<'0', '0'>' requested here
<source>:22:49: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'base3<'0', '0', '0'>' requested here
<source>:28:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'base3<'1', '0', '0', '0'>' requested here
  return base3<chars...>();
         ^
<source>:33:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator""_b3<'1', '0', '0', '0'>' requested here
  cout << 1000_b3 << endl;
              ^
<source>:12:20: note: candidate function [with c = '0']
constexpr uint64_t base3()
                   ^
<source>:19:20: note: candidate function [with c = '0', tail = <>]
constexpr uint64_t base3()
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

What is the right way to define it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, when `tail` only has 1 character (when called with the last digit `'0'` of your user defined literal), it could call either overload of `base3`

```cpp
template <char c>
constexpr uint64_t base3()  // With c as '0'
template <char c, char... tail>
constexpr uint64_t base3()  // With c as '0' and tail as an empty parameter pack
```

There is no reason to prefer one over the other, so it is ambiguous.

You need the second overload to not work with exactly 1 argument, so you can make sure it takes at least 2 arguments:

```cpp
template <char c, char second, char... tail>
constexpr uint64_t base3()
{
  static_assert(c >= '0' && c <= '2', "Not a ternary digit.");
  return ipow(3, 1+sizeof...(tail)) * (c - '0') + base3<second, tail...>();
}
```

Or do it with SFINAE:

```cpp
template <char c, char... tail>
constexpr
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(tail) != 0, uint64_t>::type
base3()
{
  static_assert(c >= '0' && c <= '2', "Not a ternary digit.");
  return ipow(3, sizeof...(tail)) * (c - '0') + base3<tail...>();
}
```

Or change it to a base case of 0 characters:

```cpp
template <typename = void>  // Can be called with an empty set of template args
constexpr uint64_t base3()
{
  return 0;
}

template <char c, char... tail>
constexpr uint64_t base3()
{
  static_assert(c >= '0' && c <= '2', "Not a ternary digit.");
  return ipow(3, sizeof...(tail)) * (c - '0') + base3<tail...>();
}
```